# How to run an activity only once like Splash screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, back-stack

In my app, I would like to run the Splash screen once at first run only but the problem is that I already placed in the `Manifest` this line: `android:noHistory="true"` which works great if I press back button and exits the app but note that the app is still in the background running, and when I press the app icon it goes back again to the Splash screen then my Registration page. I wanted to be redirected to the Registration page directly when I reopen my application.

How do I do this? Thanks ahead for any suggestions.

Comment: use shared preferences. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779929/activity-that-is-only-launched-once-after-a-new-install

Comment: use shared prefrence to set the any boolean value ,and make a class like appstart,in this get the shared preference value if its true then  launch the intent for SplashScreen,and if false launch the intent for Registration Page.

Comment: How do you visualize the splash screen? You should disable this loading in the `onResume`  method.

Comment: @Compaq LE2202x-put your code what u have tried ...

Comment: @Raghunandan Thank for the link but I don't actually get it. Should I place the `onActivityResult` on my Splash Activity or the Registration Activity? I tried both but it seemed `onActivityResult` was not called either way?

Comment: @FarhaSameer786 I updated and posted my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's what I did, in my SplashActivity(onCreate):

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("firstRun", true);
    editor.commit();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

SplashActivity(onResume):

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
    if (!firstRun) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        Log.d("TAG1", "firstRun(false): " + Boolean.valueOf(firstRun).toString());
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG1", "firstRun(true): " + Boolean.valueOf(firstRun).toString());
    }
}
```

In my RegistrationActivity(onCreate):

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
    editor.commit();

    boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
    Log.d("TAG1", "firstRun: " + Boolean.valueOf(firstRun).toString());
```

And then disabled back button to prevent going back unless the user presses Home:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Big thanks for those that contributed!

Answer (score 13):

This is how I achieved it!Hope it helps!

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class check extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences("prefs",0);
    boolean firstRun=settings.getBoolean("firstRun",false);
    if(firstRun==false)//if running for first time
    //Splash will load for first time
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstRun",true);
        editor.commit();
        Intent i=new Intent(check.this,Splash.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else
    {

        Intent a=new Intent(check.this,Main.class);
        startActivity(a);
        finish();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Instead of calling finish() on activity.To remove the activity from activity stack just use android:noHistory="true" in your manifest

Comment: very simple and very useful! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Shared Preferences** to save some boolean when you run your app at very first launch and then check that value on every launch if exits then directly start the Registration Activity.

> Although, this approach of just saving a normal value has a loop hole where, suppose your app is
>   installed on a user device and user just updated the app with new
>   version without uninstalling the first one then in that case you also
>   not gonna see the Splash as the old shared preferences will already be
>   there with that old saved value.

**So in that case you need to change the logic litle bit by saving the app version and check for app version on every launch in that way you will be able to produce real user experience.**

Have a look at this : [How to create a one-time welcome screen using Android preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398767/how-to-create-a-one-time-welcome-screen-using-android-preferences)

Comment: Thanks for this, I will be using this later but for now my I still have problem with the "run once."

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on the mention of "shared preferences", I believe the following would work, if you inserted it in onCreate() of your main activity:

```
    SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("appInfo", 0);
    boolean firstTime = settings.getBoolean("first_time", true);
    if (firstTime) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("first_time", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

After the block executes, "firstTime" should indicate whether this is the first time the app has been run.  "appInfo" is just a placeholder name for whatever you want the preferences file to be called, I believe.

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x Sorry; missed that - I hate it when people do that, too.  `ctx` stood for Context (an Activity is also a Context), which, in onCreate(), should be `this`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way it that
You can use **android:noHistory="true"** in your manifest file.

Comment: It's not working after the application is being closed and open again.

Comment: android:noHistory=“true” only makes sure the splash activity does not remain in the back stack, it does not guarantee that the splash activity won’t be OnCtreate(d) again.